# VARCHAR(MAX) Issue: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, string, error-handling, binary

My Problem is about

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I tried researching on this error and still it doesn't solve my problem. I checked all my declarations and honestly it was all `VARCHAR(MAX)`

```
  DISABLE TRIGGER membership.member_id_emergency_contact_tr_critical_change_log ON membership.member_id_emergency_contact;
  DISABLE TRIGGER membership.member_images_tru ON membership.member_images;
  DISABLE TRIGGER membership.member_other_info_tru_critical_change_log ON membership.member_other_info;
  DISABLE TRIGGER membership.member_tr_critical_change_log ON membership.[member];

DECLARE @field VARCHAR(MAX),
        @new_value VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE crit_loop CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT mccl.field, mccl.new_value FROM membership.member_critical_change_log mccl WHERE mccl.member_code = 'MEM-HO-2015-0000026'

OPEN crit_loop
FETCH crit_loop INTO @field, @new_value

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC [membership].[CommitCriticalChanges] @field, @new_value,'MEM-HO-2015-0000026';
FETCH crit_loop INTO @field, @new_value
END

CLOSE crit_loop
DEALLOCATE crit_loop

 ;ENABLE TRIGGER membership.member_id_emergency_contact_tr_critical_change_log ON membership.member_id_emergency_contact;
  ENABLE TRIGGER membership.member_images_tru ON membership.member_images;
  ENABLE TRIGGER membership.member_other_info_tru_critical_change_log ON membership.member_other_info;
  ENABLE TRIGGER membership.member_tr_critical_change_log ON membership.[member]
```

---

### COMMIT CRITICAL PROCEDURE

```
CREATE PROCEDURE membership.CommitCriticalChanges
    @field VARCHAR(MAX),
    @new_value VARCHAR(MAX),
    @member_code VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
 IF @field = 'Signature'
  UPDATE membership.member_images SET signature = @new_value WHERE    member_code = @member_code

ELSE IF @field = 'Photo'
  UPDATE membership.member_images SET photo = @new_value WHERE member_code = @member_code

END
```

Hoping to get an answer soon. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea it return this kind of error where in  fact all of my parameters are set to MAX, i checked all the columns on my db and it's max.

Comment: cant see any problem with the code shown in question, what is going on in `Some code here` section????

Comment: Specify code of PROCEDURE membership.CommitCriticalChanges

Comment: IF statements for example.. i fetch a field named photo and its value as an encrypted string.

Comment: `CODE `IF @field = 'Signature'
      UPDATE membership.member_images SET signature = @new_value WHERE member_code = @member_code
    ELSE IF @field = 'Photo'
      UPDATE membership.member_images SET photo = @new_value WHERE member_code = @member_code

Comment: @M.Ali i have some if's statements on the code here section, As you can see i fetch a field and the new value right? I got this Field name "Photo" and its newvalue is a converted byte to string and is encrypted.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude i have some if's statements on the code here section, As you can see i fetch a field and the new value right? I got this Field name "Photo" and its newvalue is a converted byte to string and is encrypted

Comment: what is the datatype of columns signature and photo in membership.member_images?

Comment: @Jasqlg The datatype is Varchar and the size is max.

Comment: put the code in the question: code in the comments is unreadable.

Comment: @Paolo done editing it.

Comment: `Photo Signature` Photo and Signature columns has VARCHAR data type the size is set to MAX

Comment: `CAST` I tried casting the new value to VARCHAR(MAX), I also tried the SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; and set it to ON after the execution of the loop, hoping that it would fix the problem. but still the error still exists.

Comment: a wild guess: there is one more trigger to disable before doing the update.

Comment: @Paolo I only have 4 triggers in the database.

Comment: `Debug` I tried debugging it in management studio and returned me that it has problem on the Open crit_loop part. but i dont know what to do next.